# Why the string modification is not taking place as expected?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I was trying to implement the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void abc(char *, char *);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *p="Hello XYZ";
    char *q="ABC";
    abc(p,q);
    printf("%s", p);
}
void abc(char *p, char *q)
{
    p+=6;
    p=q;
}
```

I believe I am modifying the references and I was expecting the output

> "Hello ABC"

but the output is

> "Hello XYZ".

Can any one explain the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. C uses pass-by-value for function argument passing. So, you cannot actually change `p` or `q` from `abc()`. To actually change `p` and `q` themselves, you'll be requiring to pass a pointer to each of them.
2. `p=q;` is not the way to copy a string, anyway. You need to make use of [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to copy a string.
3. You're making the call to `abc()` with arguments which are the pointers to string literals. If you try to modify the *values* pointed to by those input arguments, you'll face [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: From what I've understood, pass by reference is in reality pass by value because the value stored is being sent.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have a trailing superfluous `**`.

Secondly, function `abc` modifies pointer `p` which is passed to it by value, then throws away the result. Why would you expect any different behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

`p` and `q` point to **read-only** string literals.

Attempting to change the data to which they point is undefined behaviour. You can change what `p` and `q` point to (i.e. reassigning the pointers is fine).

Fortunately you are not changing them in the function `abc` since you are passing the pointers *by value*.

If you want to modify the strings, then you'd need to use `char p[] ="Hello XYZ";` etc. That creates a read-write null-terminated string of fixed length.

Answer (score 0):

There are sort of two styles of dealing with strings in C: array style and pointer style.  What you're trying to do lends itself better to array style.

In array style, you always use `strcpy` to copy strings or fragments of strings around.  You must also always make sure your arrays are big enough.

In array style, your code would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void abc(char [], char []);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char a[]="Hello XYZ";
    char b[]="ABC";
    abc(q, b);
    printf("%s", a);
}

void abc(char a[], char b[])
{
    strcpy(a+6, b);
}
```

This works, although it relies on the fact (i.e., "blindly assumes") that the string `a` passed to function `abc` is at least 6 characters longer than `b`.

Also, I have to warn you that it turns out there's actually no difference between the function signatures -- that is, the argument lists -- of your function `abc` and mine.  I rewrote the arguments to emphasize that arrays are involved, and it makes sense when you look at it that way, but eventually you'll need to understand that inside the rewritten function `abc`, the arguments `a` and `b` are still actually pointers, but it works and makes sense that way, too.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly，the char *p = "Hello XYZ",and char *q = "ABC",both of them are string constants,you can't modify the values which the points point to.

The right way modify a string,you can use arry type,or malloc some memorys to store strings.